# How to change cookie through Ajax + PHP?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, cookies

I am trying to modify a Cookie through an Ajax petition but it doesn't work. It modifies the Session but not the cookie. Here is my code:

HTML:

```
<li class="en_GB" id="1" onclick="changeLanguage('en_GB;1')"><span></span>ENGLISH</li>
```

Javascript:

```
function changeLanguage(lang){
  $.ajax({
        url: 'lib/loadLanguageList.php',
        data: {lan: lang},
        type: 'POST',
        success: function(data){
         location.reload();
        }
    });
}
```

PHP (loadLanguageList.php) / Action:

```
if(isset($_POST['lan']) && preg_match("/([a-z]+_[A-Z]+;[0-9]+)/", $_POST['lan'])){
    setUserLanguage($_POST['lan']);
}
```

PHP (loadLanguageList.php) / function EDITED*:
(Following the suggestion of @MikeBrant, I've edited the function)

```
function setUserLanguage($lan){
    $locale['value'] = "";
    $locale['id'] = "";
    if(isset($lan)){
        $lan = explode(";", $lan);
        $locale['value'] = $lan[0];
        $locale['id'] = $lan[1];
    } else if (!isset($_COOKIE["locale"])){
        $lan = $this->getUserLanguage();
        $locale['value'] = $lan[0]['value'];
        $locale['id'] = $lan[0]['id'];
    }
    setcookie("locale","",time()-2592000);
    setcookie("locale_id","",time()-2592000);
    setcookie("locale",$locale['value'],time()+60*60*24*30);
    setcookie("locale_id",$locale['id'],time()+60*60*24*30);
    print_r($locale);
    $_SESSION['locale'] = $locale['value'];
    $_SESSION['locale_id'] = $locale['id'];
    require_once(ROOT."/lib/utils/localization.php");
}
```

But the cookie is not being deleted and the `print_r` print `$locale` variable as it should be. I don't understand why the `setcookie` function didn't work.

Comment: Do you have error reporting enabled

Comment: Hi @DanFromGermany, yes I've and I don't get any error.

Comment: Maybe you your `if` statements do not evaluate what you are trying to get it to, do you see cookie headers getting sent through console (firebug)? I'm not quite sure wether `$_COOKIE = ...` is enough or you have to resend the cookie with `setcookie()`

Comment: @DanFromGermany I think that the third `if` evaluate what I'm trying to do, doesn't it? I don't see cookie headers through console. I've tried replacing `$_COOKIE['..'] = ...` to `setcookie()` and still not working

Comment: Your if conditionals seem to be oddly structured.  Why keep checking for `isset($lan)` for example?  You have already checked it in your first conditional, so everything that depends on that condition should be nested underneath it.  I also think you could benefit from some `else` usage. Try to restructure that code block to where the code path and logic as to how you are supposed to go through it are more clear.

Comment: Hi @MikeBrant, ty for your answer. I'm doing by this way because that script is not only for change cookies through Ajax. This script is also being used to set a cookie to users who visit a page and have not a `$_COOKIE` set.

Comment: @IIIVictorious What difference does that make? If the function is called, it will still be evaluated against all those conditionals regardless as to whether the request is made via AJAX or a regular synchronous request. Also, have you considered simply setting the cookie in javascript?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, let's rewrite your function to where it makes better logic sense in terms of the code path flow (i.e. we have simplified the conditionals).

```
function setUserLanguage($lan){
    $locale['value'] = "";
    $locale['id'] = "";
    if(isset($lan)){
        $lan = explode(";", $lan);
        $locale['value'] = $lan[0];
        $locale['id'] = $lan[1];
        if(!isset($_COOKIE["locale"])){
            setcookie("locale",$locale['value'],time()+60*60*24*30);
            setcookie("locale_id",$locale['id'],time()+60*60*24*30);
        } else {
            $_COOKIE["locale"] = $locale['value'];
            $_COOKIE["locale_id"] = $locale['id'];
        }
    } else if (!isset($_COOKIE["locale"])){
        $lan = $this->getUserLanguage();
        $locale['value'] = $lan[0]['value'];
        $locale['id'] = $lan[0]['id'];
        setcookie("locale",$locale['value'],time()+60*60*24*30);
        setcookie("locale_id",$locale['id'],time()+60*60*24*30);
    }
    $_SESSION['locale'] = $locale['value'];
    $_SESSION['locale_id'] = $locale['id'];
    require_once(ROOT."/lib/utils/localization.php");
}
```

Now let's walk through the use cases here.  Let's say the user already has a `locale` cookie set and they are trying to change it.

This user would pass this conditional:

```
if(isset($lan))
```

And should fail this conditional

```
if(!isset($_COOKIE["locale"]))
```

This means this code block would be executed:

```
$_COOKIE["locale"] = $locale['value'];
$_COOKIE["locale_id"] = $locale['id'];
```

This would change the cookie value for the duration of the script execution only, as nothing in the response to the browser would trigger a change in cookie value.

My guess is that you want to ALWAYS call `setcookie()`.

Also I would think the whole `(!isset($lan))` section of code could be removed in favor for throwing some kind of error, as having a "set" function without passing it a value doesn't seem to make much sense.

Comment: I've made some corrections in my code, but when still not working. I've modified the question with details :) Thank you for your help

Comment: What do you mean when you say `setcookie()` doesn't work?  What are you expecting it to do? Set cookie in essence does nothing but send headers to the browser.  IF you are expecting it to set a value in `$_COOKIE` (perhaps for use by your localization library that is included), then it doesn't do that, you would need to specifically set `$_COOKIE` as well.  `$_COOKIE` in and of itself is simply an auto-popoulated variable of cookie data send with browser request.